# Caddy 2 - Caddyfile - Getting ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, webserver, caddy, caddyfile

I've tried to setup a Caddy server, to handle auto SSL generating for my clients. But I keep getting errors, though sometimes it works, and I have no idea why. I'm new to Caddy, and could use some pointers to what to try next.

**Using:**

Ubuntu 22.04

Caddy v2.6.4

**Use case:**

I have a SaaS platform, where clients can sign up, and enter their domain name. Clients then make CNAME or A record to point to my Caddy server *`dns.example.com`*.

If I create a test *`test.example.com`* and point it to the Caddy server *`dns.example.com`*, it works fine on HTTP. But if I try on HTTPS, I get a `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.

The interesting part is, sometimes, out of the blue, som of my test actually works on HTTPS. So I must be close, and something must be right, but not quite there yet.

**The Current Caddyfile:**

```
{
        on_demand_tls {
                ask app.example.com/tls-check
        }

        storage redis caddy_ssl_certificates
}

:80 {
        respond /health "Im healthy!" 200

        reverse_proxy * app.example.com {
                header_up Host {host}
                header_up X-Fwd-For {remote_host}
                header_up X-Fwd-Proto {scheme}
                header_up X-Caddy-Hash mysecret
                health_timeout 5s
        }
}

:443 {
        tls email@example.com {
                on_demand
        }

        reverse_proxy * app.example.com {
                header_up Host {host}
                header_up X-Fwd-For {remote_host}
                header_up X-Fwd-Proto {scheme}
                header_up X-Caddy-Hash mysecret
                health_timeout 5s
        }
}
```

The above works fine on HTTP, and if i try to force HTTPS with replaceing the listener on port 80 I just get `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.

```
:80 {
    respond /health "Im healthy!" 200
    redir https://{host}{uri}
}
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting ask directive line and retry. Ask url with domain name as part of query string should return 200 status code.